# How Would I program my Tic Tac Toe A.I. to only choose blank boxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a Tic Tac Toe game using javascript, and I've made my an a.i., that selects random boxes on its turn. However, it may choose the same box twice or even a box which the player (which is X) has chosen. Here is the code:

```
                   <!DOCTYPE html>
                   <html>
                   <body>

                   <input type="button" id="k1" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">  
                   <input type="button" id="k2" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <input type="button" id="k3" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <br />
                   <input type="button" id="k4" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <input type="button" id="k5" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <input type="button" id="k6" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <br />
                   <input type="button" id="k7" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <input type="button" id="k8" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <input type="button" id="k9" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
                   <br />

                   <script>
                   var nummoves=0;
                   var nummoves1=1;
                   var nummoves2=2;
                   var nummoves3=3;
                   var nummoves4=4;
                   var nummoves5=5;
                   var nummoves6=6;
                   var nummoves7=7;
                   var nummoves8=8;
                   var nummoves9=9;
                   var comp;

                   function tictactoe(square)
                   {

                   var check=["c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9"]
                   check[0]=document.getElementById("k1");
                   check[1]=document.getElementById("k2");
                   check[2]=document.getElementById("k3");
                   check[3]=document.getElementById("k4");
                   check[4]=document.getElementById("k5");
                   check[5]=document.getElementById("k6");
                   check[6]=document.getElementById("k7");
                   check[7]=document.getElementById("k8");
                   check[8]=document.getElementById("k9");
                   comp=check[Math.floor(Math.random()*check.length)];


                   if(nummoves==0)
                   {
                   square.value="X";
                   }

                   if(nummoves1==1)
                   {
                   comp.value="O";
                   }


                   if(nummoves2==2)
                   {
                   square.value="X";
                   }

                   if(nummoves3==3)
                   {
                   comp.value="O";
                   }

                   if(nummoves4==4)
                   {
                   square.value="X";
                   }

                   if(nummoves5==5)
                   {
                   comp.value="O";
                    }


                 if(nummoves6==6)
                 {
                 square.value="X";
                 }

                if(nummoves7==7)
                {
                comp.value="O";
                }


                if(nummoves8==8)
                {
                 square.value="X";
                }

              if(nummoves9==9)
               {
               comp.value="O";;
               }
              }




               </script>
                </body>
                 </html>
```

So how would I change this code (but not entirely!), so that the a.i. knows only to choose a blank box?

Also, it it possible to make a clever A.I., e.g. it can block the player from getting three in a row, or even try to get three in a row itself.

Comment: when an answer is useful please +1 it and or select it

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the marks made (perhaps in an array) and have the script check the array to see whether the spot is empty before marking it; if it's not empty the script would need to pick a different spot.

Or add this in place of `comp=check[Math.floor(Math.random()*check.length)]`:

```
var checking = true; // use this for the loop condition
while (checking)
{
    comp = check[Math.floor(Math.random()*check.length)];
    if (comp.value == "  ") // check to see that the square is empty
    {
        checking = false; // if so, set the loop condition to false so the loop ends
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this very quickly. The only thing that changes is the code in `<script>` and remove *onclick* attributes. Read comments in code to see what happens.

```
var squares = [], i = 10, move_number = 1;
while(--i) // build array of choices
    squares[i-1] = document.getElementById('k'+i), // put square in array
    squares[i-1].addEventListener('click', function () {tictactoe(this);}, false); // attach click listener

// `squares` keeps track of available squares

function randomSquare() { // A.I. square chooser
    var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * squares.length ),
        e = squares[i];
    squares.splice(i,1); // remove choice from available
    return e;
}

function tictactoe(square) { // passing `this` as first arg
    var i;
    square || (square = randomSquare()); // if no arg
    if (move_number % 2) {
        i = squares.indexOf(square);
        if (i === -1) return; // square taken, do nothing
        else squares.splice(i,1); // remove square from available
        square.value="X";
        ++move_number;
        tictactoe(); // A.I. turn
    } else {
        square.value="O";
        ++move_number;
    }
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StgU4/).

Comment: This works perfectly well Paul S. Although I have to say, this does look like advanced code and i am a newbie in JavaScript so I don't entirely understand of all this code despite the comments; so if possible could you please explain methodically what each line of code means. Nonetheless thanks, because it actually works.

Comment: Don't mind me asking, but are you a professional programmer, and even if you're not, how long did it take you to get to this stage because I've been tampering on this for weeks yet it seems like it only took you a few minutes and you had the answer

Comment: Do you know how you could make the a.i. clever so it blocks you getting three-in-a-row, or it tries to get that itself.

Comment: It took me about 10 minutes, writing a full AI algorithm will take quite a bit longer, I'd imagine. `++n` means increase `n` by `1` and then if `n` is not `0` it is like saying `true` (e.g. in the `while` and in `if`). To understand how `.splice` works look [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). [`.addEventListener` **here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener). [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns element index or `-1`.